# What is wrong with my angular factory promise?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am loading a Google map and when I navigate to /map it loads the the markers to populate the map.  The problem is that the rest of the javascript runs and executes before the markers have loaded.  What I thought would solve it would be to return a promise in the factory that retrieves the map data.  This didn't work though.

Can anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong?

In the console I see this:

```
angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
at Object.link (http://localhost/logintest/js/app.js:586:55)
```

Line 586 refers to this line (in the directive):

```
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lastElement.lat, lastElement.lon),
```

I get the `lastElement` like so:

```
var lastElement = scope.arrLocations[scope.arrLocations.length - 1];
```

Factory:

```
app.factory('map', ['$q', function($q){

var map={};
var mapInfoItems=[];

map.getMapInfo = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var mapitems = firebase.database().ref('mapinfo/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
    mapitems.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
        mapInfoItems.push(snapshot.val());
        deferred.resolve(mapInfoItems);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};

    return map;
}]);
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('mapController', ['$scope', 'map', function($scope, map){
    $scope.myLocations = {};
    $scope.arrLocations = [];
    $scope.mapLocations = map.getMapInfo();

    for(var i=0; i<$scope.mapLocations.length; i++){
        $scope.myLocations.title   = $scope.mapLocations[i].name;
        $scope.myLocations.content = $scope.mapLocations[i].message;  
        $scope.myLocations.lat     = $scope.mapLocations[i].lat;
        $scope.myLocations.lon     = $scope.mapLocations[i].lon;
        $scope.arrLocations.push($scope.myLocations);
    }

}]);
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="mapController">
    <my-map get-map-fn="getMap()"></my-map>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: I've added a bit more detail.

Comment: OK so something is wrong with the creation of `arrLocations`. Let's log the prior step in the console and see what it looks like. Maybe `console.log($scope.myLocations);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map.getMapInfo()` returns a promise but you are treating it as if it returns an array in the controller

Also you keep overwriting the properties of the same object in your `for` loop and pushing the same object reference into an array. This means all elements in the array will end up with the last value set in the loop...because they are all references to one object

Replace

```
$scope.mapLocations = map.getMapInfo();
```

With

```
map.getMapInfo().then(function(locations){
   for(var i=0; i<locations.length; i++){
        // create new object each iteration
        var obj ={
           title  : locations[i].name,
           content: locations[i].message,
           // ... etc    
        }     

        $scope.arrLocations.push(obj);
    }    
});
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense to me, looks like it should work.  I'm having a look at it just now but I'll probably need to come back to it later, as its 2am here.  Thank you :)